# What is the difference in HttpClient in .net 4.0 and .net 4.5

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on a project that is currently using an early pre-release .net 4.0 version on HttpClient in System.Web.Http namespace. We know that this version causes conflicts with .net 4.5 version.

We are thinking of upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 and we know that this is going to install .net 4.5 (which we dont currently use). My question(s) is, how drastically different are the two version of the HttpClient class? Or, would the use of the latest .net 4.0 version of HttpClient be enough to get us to a stage where we could install .net 4.5 and not have any conflicts?

Cheers

NCBL

Comment: For reference, add links discussing the encountered conflicts (possible other SO posts) to the question.

Comment: The conflicts between the 4.0 HttpClient and .net 4.5 are long gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two versions are identical from an API perspective and 4.5 is backwards compatible with 4.0 from a functionality perspective. The 4.5 version does support a couple new features on `WebRequestHandler` (`ContinueTimeout` & `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`) so avoid those.

You shouldn't run into any conflicts when using this library and running on 4.5. The 4.5 version has the same name as the 4.0 version and the framework will unify to the inbox version.